# How to change these two functions from JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setYear()
{

    var d = new Date(); 

    var cur = document.getElementById('CYear'); 
    var prev = document.getElementById('PYear'); 
    var next = document.getElementById('NYear'); 
    var optionC, optionP, optionN; 

    for (var i = d.getFullYear() - 10; i <= d.getFullYear() + 10; i++) 
    { 
        optionC = document.createElement("option"); 
        optionC.setAttribute("value", i); 
        optionC.innerHTML = i; 
        cur.appendChild(optionC); 
    };
    for (var i = d.getFullYear() - 10; i < d.getFullYear() + 10; i++) 
    { 
        optionP = document.createElement("option"); 
        optionP.setAttribute("value", i); 
        optionP.innerHTML = i; 
        prev.appendChild(optionP); 
    }; 
    for (var i = d.getFullYear() - 10; i <= d.getFullYear() + 10; i++) 
    { 
        optionN = document.createElement("option"); 
        optionN.setAttribute("value", i); 
        optionN.innerHTML = i; 
        next.appendChild(optionN); 
    }; 
    cur.value=d.getFullYear();
    prev.value=d.getFullYear()-1;
    next.value=d.getFullYear()+1;   
}
function setYear1(obj)
{
    var prev = document.getElementById('PYear');
    var next = document.getElementById('NYear');   
    
    prev.value = Number(obj.value) - 1;
    next.value = Number(obj.value) + 1;
}

function onlyNumbers(evt)
            {
                var evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
                var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
                if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode!=44)
                {
                    alert("Enter numerals only in this field!");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }


</script>
```

I need to change this two function from JavaScript to jQuery. Are there any converters for doing this?

Comment: jQuery is a library/framework built on top of javascript - they aren't different languages.  What exactly is it you need to change?

Comment: why do you need it to use jQuery? there's nothing wrong with plain javascript. in most cases, plain javascript is faster.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding jQuery to an existing project with JavaScript on it shouldn't break any existing JavaScript unless you're using a conflicting framework such as prototype, in which case you can often get away with both being present simply by setting jQuery to noConflict mode.
>
> There's certainly no need to rewrite working JavaScript functions into jQuery if they're working fine as they are unless your primary goal is to improve efficiency / write shorter code or even if it's simply because the JavaScript has become too cumbersome to maintain.
>
> In summary if you just want to add some new jQuery functionality to a website; why not just add it and leave the existing JavaScript as is?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305763/1188942

---

As for converters, I haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just an extension of javascript that deals (mostly) with selecting and manipulating DOM elements. So no, there isn't going to be a converter. I'd suggest actually *learning* jQuery -- it's unbelievably useful.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Blazemonger technically it's an answer. The question is "how do I convert this to jQuery?" and the answer is essentially "you need to learn jQuery." And then there's the added bonus of explaining what jQuery is.